# Seeking birth/baptism record for Michael Zomolsky born 1913 in Ukraine?

Tags: 20th-century, birth-records, baptism-records, ukraine

I am trying to verify the birth family of my grandfather, Michael Zomolsky born 1913 Ukraine.

I believe he had these family members:

- father: Stanley,
- mother: Anna
- brothers: John and Sam
- one sister

How could I locate a birth/baptism record for him, as my starting point to finding those for his siblings too?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than looking for something open-ended like "Looking for relatives ...".  Also, as per our Privacy Policy in the [help] take care when asking about anyone born less than 100 years ago.

Comment: You could start by looking for a birth/baptism record for Michael Zomolsky.  That would be a focused question and might verify his parents' names.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! There is an article in the [help] that gives tips on how to How to ask: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask -- this question could be improved with information about what research you've already done. You can use the edit link underneath your question at any time to update your question.